# react native navigate to another stack with params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from 'react-native-screens/native-stack';


enableScreens();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const WardrobeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const OutfitStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const CreateLookStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export const WardrobeNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <WardrobeStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            initialRouteName='Wardrobe'>
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="Wardrobe" component={Wardrobe} /> // <== navigate to here with params
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="AddFirstItem" component={AddFirstItem} />
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="RetakeContinue" component={RetakeContinue} />
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="CategoryBrand" component={CategoryBrand} />
            <WardrobeStack.Screen name="DeleteCategory" component={DeleteCategory} />
        </WardrobeStack.Navigator>
    );
}

export const OutfitNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <OutfitStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            initialRouteName='LookBook'>
            <OutfitStack.Screen name="Outfits" component={Outfits} />
            <OutfitStack.Screen name="LookBook" component={LookBook} />
            <OutfitStack.Screen name="LookBookList" component={LookBookList} /> // <== navigate from here
            <OutfitStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
            <OutfitStack.Screen name="ShoppingList" component={ShoppingList} />
        </OutfitStack.Navigator>
    );
}

export const CreateLookNavigator = () => {
return (
  <CreateLookStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
    initialRouteName="NewLook">
    <CreateLookStack.Screen name="NewLook">
        {props => (
        <NewLook
            {...props}
            initialParams={{
                lookSaveType: AppConstants.DEFAULT_LOOK_SAVE_TYPE,
            }}
        />
        )}
    </CreateLookStack.Screen>
    <CreateLookStack.Screen name="SaveLook" component={SaveLook} />
  </CreateLookStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export const ProfileNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <ProfileStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            initialRouteName='ProfileOnbarding'>
            <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileOnbarding" component={ProfileOnboarding} />
            <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileAllSet" component={ProfileAllSet} />
        </ProfileStack.Navigator>
    );
}

export const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <RootStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            initialRouteName='Main'
            mode='modal'>
            <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="Brands" component={BrandStores} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="ItemScreen" component={ItemScreen} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="CreateLook" component={CreateLookNavigator} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="ShoppingList" component={ShoppingList} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="ProfileOnboarding" component={ProfileNavigator} />
            {/* add full screen appear as modal */}
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
}

export const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
    return (

        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Outfits"
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    switch (route.name) {
                        case 'Explore':
                            return focused ? <ActiveTeleIcon /> : <InactiveTeleIcon />
                        case 'Bookings':
                            return focused ? <ActiveBookingIcon /> : <InactiveBookingIcon />
                        case 'Wardrobe':
                            return focused ? <ActiveWardrobeIcon /> : <InactiveWardrobeIcon />
                        case 'Outfits':
                            return focused ? <ActiveOutfitsIcon /> : <InactiveOutfitsIcon />
                        case 'Chat':
                            return focused ? <ActiveChatIcon /> : <InactiveChatIcon />
                    }
                },
            })}
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
                inactiveTintColor: Colors.SECONDARY_TEXT,
                statusBarStyle: 'light-content',
                style: styles.tabContainer,
                labelStyle: styles.labelStyle,
                allowFontScaling: true,
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Explore"
                component={Explore}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Explore'
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Bookings"
                component={Bookings}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Bookings',
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Wardrobe"
                component={WardrobeNavigator}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Wardrobe',
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Outfits"
                component={OutfitNavigator}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Outfits',
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Chat"
                component={Chat}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Chat',
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};
```

I want to navigate from `LookBookList` to `Wardrobe`, this is what I am doing in **lookbook-list.js** file.

```
  <HeaderBar
    backButton
    leftClick={() => navigation.goBack()}
    rightIcon={<HangerIcon />}
    rightIconClick={() => {
      navigation.navigate('Wardrobe', {openModal: true});
    }}
  />
```

My **Wardrobe.js** file:

```
export const Wardrobe = ({route}) => {
    console.log('route.params', route.params) // <== this is undefined ???
    const {openModal} = route.params;

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(openModal);
```

I am getting following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.openModal')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have resolved the issue using React's `Context` API.

created a context in **wardrobe-context.js**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const WardrobeContext = React.createContext();

function WardrobeProvider(props) {
  const [isAddItemModalOpen, setIsAddItemModalOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <WardrobeContext.Provider
      value={{isAddItemModalOpen, setIsAddItemModalOpen}}>
      {props.children}
    </WardrobeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default WardrobeProvider;
```

the in **navigation.js** file, wrapped my Root Navigation Stack with `WardrobeProvider`:

```
export const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <WardrobeProvider> // <== wrapper context provider
            <RootStack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
                initialRouteName='Main'
                mode='modal'>
                <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="Brands" component={BrandStores} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="ItemScreen" component={ItemScreen} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="CreateLook" component={CreateLookNavigator} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="ShoppingList" component={ShoppingList} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="StylistInstructions" component={ProfileNavigator} />
                {/* add full screen appear as modal */}
            </RootStack.Navigator>
        </WardrobeProvider>
    );
}
```

Finally, in **Wardrobe.js**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { WardrobeContext } from '../../../context/wardrobe-context';
export const Wardrobe = () => {
    const {isAddItemModalOpen, setIsAddItemModalOpen} = useContext(WardrobeContext);

    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            setIsVisible(isAddItemModalOpen) // <== set value here to open modal
          return () => setIsAddItemModalOpen(false); // <== clear/reset the value on navigation change
        }, [isAddItemModalOpen])
    );
```

`useFocusEffect` is used to set the value of `isAddItemModalOpen` of `isVisible` State when the `Wardrobe.js` screen is focused and the value in context is set to false when the screen is not focused or in other words when the user navigates to another screen.

the to navigate from **lookbook-list.js** to **Wardrobe.js** updating context value:

```
  import {WardrobeContext} from '../../../context/wardrobe-context';

  <HeaderBar
    backButton
    leftClick={() => navigation.goBack()}
    rightIcon={<HangerIcon />}
    rightClick={() => {
      wardrobeContext.setIsAddItemModalOpen(true); // <== update context here
      navigation.navigate('Wardrobe'); // <== and then navigate
    }}
  />
```

Improvement suggestions are welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code I think the problem is that you can also reach `WardrobeNavigator` from your tabs and not just from navigate. Since your initial screen is `Wardrobe` in the `WardrobeNavigator` and since you're not passing `initialParams`, `route.params.openModal` gets evaluated before the params have been set on navigate.

To protect against it being undefined and to provide a default value we have access to this syntax:

```
const openModal = route.params?.openModal ?? false; // So false is the default value here
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#no-more-getparam

**Update**

The reason it's not working is because you're updating the params of the `WardrobeNavigator` and not the `Wardrobe`. Since you want to pass params to a nested screen you can do something like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Wardrobe', {
  screen: 'Wardrobe',
  params: { openModal: true },
})
```

Comment: I tried `initialParams`, I can see the route.params.openModal now but when i navigate from LookbookList component using `navigation.navigate('Wardrobe', {openModal: true})` the screen changes but value doesn't change, It's still `false`;

Comment: Thanks this worked but my modal wasn't opening as openModal was passed as an initial state to setState so I had to setState again in useEffect passing down the openModal param. Then next issue was on further navigation the route param wasn't clearing or resetting, which again required useEffect to do so. I have resorted to react's Context api to handle it. I'll answer with my implementation for more details. Thanks a lot for your help.